# Routing issue in Angular ui-router using href

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I have made one state and trying to navigate to other page. There is no error in console but navigation is not working either.

index.html

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <a href='#/first-msg'>link</a>
    <div ui-view></div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="application.js"></script>
</body>
```

application.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('firstMessage', {
        url: '/first-msg',
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
}]);
app.controller("homeCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "This is home";
}]);
```

when i click on link, the url is like

```
.../index.html#%2Ffirst-msg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ui-router`, you should not use `href`. Use `ui-sref` instead:

```
<a ui-sref="firstMessage">link</a>
```

*Note I use the **state name**, and not its URL.*

---

## [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9yLj2wtL/)